# ExtJS GridPanel numberColumn - sort issue

Tags: extjs

I have a grid Panel with 4 columns, one of these is numeric (number up to 4 digit), and I would like to sort the row by this colum. My problem is Ext JS sorts the rows as if the column was textual, so 5 is sorted after 3000.

I tried to use a numberColumn instead of a normal column (specifying the x-type in the columns of the GridPanel), but it doesn't change the sorting.

Thus I tried to format the numbers so 5 would appear like 0005, and 0005 would be before 3000. But the format options of the numberColumn do not appear to let me specify a minimal number of digit (in Java, using NumberFormat, 0000 would work, but here it doesn't).

So I put a renderer to force my number to appear with 4 digits, it works, but it seems that the sort method use the values before beeing rendered, wich is quite logical.

I'm stuck after trying all my ideas, does anyone have a clue?

Comment: What are you using as a store? Have you configured the type over there? It should be something like: `{name: 'price', type: 'float'}`

Comment: It was with "type: 'int'". I tried with "type: 'float'", but it doesn't work either.

Comment: do you have a running sample somewhere ?

Comment: Are you using a local store or a remote store ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a remote store sort, then the sorting is done remotely (the database, like mysql). So what is the type of column on the database for that field? If it's a char or varchar, then that's the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar issue, the column type doesn't fix this. To have a proper ordering the type in model should be numeric.

1) Set your field type as integer in model definition.

```
Ext.define('myModel', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  fields: [{ name: 'myField', type: 'int' }]
});
```

2) Create a Store using that model.

```
var myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',{
  model: 'myModel'
});
```

3) Define a GridPanel using the store and link your field as dataIndex into columns definition.

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel',{
  store: myStore,
  columns: [{
    header: 'Numbers',  dataIndex: 'myField'
  }]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem where by exj grids sort by each digit in your number, so for example a list might be reordered to 1, 2, 22, 3, 4, 41, 5... for what its worth, i found in **extjs4**, that defining the type as int in the model did the trick, I havent specified the local or remote sort but it seems to be working...

Answer (score 0):

```
Ext.define('ExtMVC.model.Contato', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  fields: [{'id', type: 'int'}, 'name', 'phone', 'email']
});
```

This is my code that connects to a MySQL. I followed this -> {'id', type: 'int'}, and it work out fine... Thank you all! I'm using Ext js 4.2.x